# Problems with beating 256bit key into 32bit round keys

Tags: c, cryptography

I'm trying to beat key into round keys.
I use the struct to keep keys:

```
struct key
{
    u_int64_t key[4];
    u_int32_t round_keys[8];
};
```

Using the func to initialize the struct values:

```
struct key *set_key()
{
    struct key *key = malloc(sizeof(*key));
    memset(key, 0, 4 * sizeof(u_int64_t) + 8 * sizeof(u_int32_t));
    key->key[0] = 0x1;
    key->key[1] = 0x1;
    key->key[2] = 0x1;
    key->key[3] = 0x1;
    return key;
};
```

And using the func to beat key into round keys:

```
void key_to_round_keys(struct key *key)
{
    memcpy(key->round_keys, key->key, sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memcpy(key->round_keys + sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memcpy(key->round_keys + 2 * sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + 2 * sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memcpy(key->round_keys + 3 * sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + 3 * sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memcpy(key->round_keys + 4 * sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + 4 * sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memcpy(key->round_keys + 5 * sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + 5 * sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memcpy(key->round_keys + 6 * sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + 6 * sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
    memcpy(key->round_keys + 7 * sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + 7 * sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
};
```

My main func is

```
int main() {
    struct key *key = set_key();
    key_to_round_keys(key);
    printf("Key[1]: %llu\nRound key 1: %d", key->key[0], key->round_keys[0]);
    delete_key(key);
}
```

The problem is that during beating the key into round keys i've got the values 
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} for my round keys. but it should be like {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}.
Why could it happen so?

Comment: In `set_key`, `key = malloc(sizeof(&key));` should be `key = malloc(sizeof(*key));`.

Comment: Also, you can simplify `memset(key, 0, 4 * sizeof(u_int64_t) + 8 * sizeof(u_int32_t));` to `memset(key, 0, sizeof(*key));`.

Comment: Right, thanks! But the problem is still the same. I made the memset this way just to make it explicit

Comment: When you add an integer to a pointer, the address in the pointer is increased by the integer multiplied by the size of the thing pointed to, so the pointer arithmetic in `key_to_round_keys` is all wrong.

Comment: @IanAbbott, uhh, So i just need to add & before every pointer there?

Comment: @GregFrost He's saying that the compiler adds `*sizeof(u_uint32_t)` for you. When you do `key->key + 2*sizeof(u_uint32_t)` for example, the compiler actually does `key->key + 2*sizeof(u_uint32_t)*sizeof(u_uint64_t)` which is all wrong.

Comment: Understood. So i just can write `memcpy(key->round_keys + 1, key->key + 1, 1);`?

Comment: `memcpy(key->round_keys + 1, key->key + 1, 1);` would only copy a single byte.

Comment: Please don't beat the keys. They're trying their best to keep your secrets secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer arithmetic in `key_to_round_keys` is all wrong. For pointer addition, `((p) + (i))` is equivalent to `(&((p)[i]))`.

Let's assume `sizeof(u_int32_t)` is 4 on your system (which is quite likely), then:

```
memcpy(key->round_keys + 7 * sizeof(u_int32_t), key->key + 7 * sizeof(u_int32_t), sizeof(u_int32_t));
```

would be equivalent to:

```
memcpy(&key->round_keys[7 * 4], &key->key[7 * 4], sizeof(u_int32_t));
```

or:

```
memcpy(&key->round_keys[28], &key->key[28], sizeof(u_int32_t));
```

However, the `round_keys` array member is only 8 elements long, and the `key` array member is only 4 elements long, so both the source and destination of this `memcpy` call are out of bounds.

---

Since your `set_key` function initializes the `key` array member of the `struct key` to `{1, 1, 1, 1}` (four 64-bit numbers), and you have indicated that you desire the `key_to_round_keys` function to copy that to the `round_keys` array member as `{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}`, it seems that you want `round_keys[0]` to contain the upper 32 bits of `key[0]` and `round_keys[1]` to contain the lower 32 bits of `key[0]`. Or in general, `round_keys[2*n]` should contain the upper 32 bits of `key[n]`, and `round_keys[2*n+1]` should contain the lower 32 bits of `key[n]`. That can be done as follows:

```
void key_to_round_keys(struct key *key)
{
    key->round_keys[0] = key->key[0] >> 32;
    key->round_keys[1] = key->key[0] & 0xFFFFFFFFu;
    key->round_keys[2] = key->key[1] >> 32;
    key->round_keys[3] = key->key[1] & 0xFFFFFFFFu;
    key->round_keys[4] = key->key[2] >> 32;
    key->round_keys[5] = key->key[2] & 0xFFFFFFFFu;
    key->round_keys[6] = key->key[3] >> 32;
    key->round_keys[7] = key->key[3] & 0xFFFFFFFFu;
};
```

Or:

```
void key_to_round_keys(struct key *key)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
    {
        key->round_keys[2*n] = key->key[n] >> 32;
        key->round_keys[2*n+1] = key->key[n] & 0xFFFFFFFFu;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But i can't understand, why should we use `& 0xFFFFFFFFu`;

Comment: `& 0xFFFFFFFFu` applies a bit mask that strips off everything above the first 32 bits. It isn't needed in this case since `round_keys[x]` is only 32 bits wide so everything above the first 32 bits will be stripped off anyway. But I like to use a bit mask anyway.